# when I try to run my flutter project it shows this error

Tags: android, flutter, dart

C:/Users/DELL/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/audioplayers-4.1.0/lib/src/audio_cache.dart:92:29: Error: The getter 'byteData' isn't defined for the class 'AudioCache'.

- 'AudioCache' is from 'package:audioplayers/src/audio_cache.dart' ('/C:/Users/DELL/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/audioplayers-4.1.0/lib/src/audio_cache.dart').
  audio_cache.dart:1
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'byteData'.
  await file.writeAsBytes(byteData.buffer.asUint8List());
  ^^^^^^^^

The project is from a course is from Dr. Angela Yu, Section 9, Xylophone app.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

try deleting this folder Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ run flutter clean, and then flutter pub get